# Zend Rest Controller for api and web together

Tags: php, zend-framework

Does anyone have experience implementing an api with Zend framework? I see it's possible to implement index, get, post, put, delete for the api, then implement new and edit actions for the web in the same controller. But is this a good idea? I want to know if this implementation has been tested enough that people don't get problems with it down the road.

Answer (score 3):

I've had success using the [Context Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch) to give 'API' access using the same URI structure as the 'normal' site. Then API consumers just have to POST data like a normal form. Depending on the complexity of your needs, that might work for you.

Also, it should be noted that [Zend provides a REST router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.rest) that may be useful.

Comment: @sullivan I wasn't actually using the rest router, in my case the API was added after the initial work was done. So I simply used the context switch to provide an easily parsed format of each 'page'. I've thought of using `.xml` but haven't pursued it yet. Seems it would take customizing the route someway.